# What are some alternatives to barplot?

Tags: r, database, visualization, bar-chart

I have the following dataset which consists of several aspects of evaluation for a certain agent for 2014 and 2015 respectively:

```
mydata<-data.frame(X2014 = c(200,1500,14, 1499), X2015 = c(100,1657,16, 1234))
```

I am trying to create a comparative plot which helps to see if 2015 is overall a better or worse year  compared to 2014 and on which aspects (variables). I have already tried using a simple barplot for each year (give or take a few adjustments to make it look nice):

```
barplot(as.matrix(mydata))
```

However, I was wondering if there was an alternative to help visualize a dataset of such kind. Help would be appreaciated.

Comment: What do the values mean? CAN they just be stacked? Is it always four?

Comment: Yes, they can be stacked because they are measured in comparable units. For instance:

2014: Income = 200, Costs = 1500, Sales = 14, Losses = 1499
2015: Income = 100, Costs = 1657, Sales = 16, Losses = 1234

It is always four in this case. What I am looking for is an alternative to bar plots in order to visualize (compare) all aspects of the year simultaneously.

Comment: IMHO, in this example case, the best option would simply be a table with the actual figures rather than any graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear (with a crucial detail only appearing in a comment), but something like this might be what you want

```
mydata <- data.frame(X2014 = c(200,1500,14, 1499), 
                     X2015 = c(100,1657,16, 1234),
                     what = c("Income", "Costs", "Sales", "Losses" ))

library(tidyr)
mydata_long <- gather(mydata, year, value, X2014:X2015)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata_long, aes(year, value, colour = what)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = what)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Perhaps this is more appropriate, in case the units of measurement are different for each variable:

```
ggplot(mydata_long, aes(year, value, colour = what)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = what)) +
  facet_wrap(~what, scales = 'free') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

We can put the plots in a stack so the year to year comparison is easier to see:

```
ggplot(mydata_long, aes(year, value, colour = what)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(group = what)) +
  facet_wrap(~what, scales = 'free', ncol = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]